# I have a problem with my first C code, i tried a lot of things but i always have the same error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main();
{
    printf("Hello word");
    return 0;
}
```

i don't know why but i get an error when i run this script. It tells me

error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I don't know what to do :/

Comment: C is not a scripting language and that is not a script.

Comment: How did you compile your program?

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the semicolon after `main();` so it reads: `main()`. C uses semicolons to terminate statements and a function is not a statement, it's a declaration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() // removed semicolon
{
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Hello wor`l`d"...